# Cannot load associated records from a router (ember 1.0.0 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.1)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a router that loads a "Place".

```
App.PlaceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params) {
            return this.store.find('place', params.place_id);
        },
        setupController: function(controller, model) {
            this._super(controller, model);

            //The promise way ?
            var placeId = model.get('id');
            var myRecords = this.store.find('record', {place:placeId}).then(function(recs){
                    console.log("DOES IT HAPPEN ?"); //Never logged
                    this.controllerFor('records').set('content', recs);
            });

            //Or is the good way below ?
            //this.controllerFor('records').set('content', myRecords);

            //The only that works (which is not I want but displays as I would like):
            //this.controllerFor('records').set('content', App.Record.FIXTURES);

            this.controllerFor('places').set('content', this.store.find('place'));
        },
        renderTemplate: function(){
            this.render('place', {
                    controller: 'place'  
            });
            this.render('display-graph-list', {
                    into: 'place',
                    outlet: 'graphs',
                    controller: 'records'  
            });
        }
    });
```

This Place has associated "Records".

```
App.Place = DS.Model.extend({
        name: attr('string')
        , desc: attr('string')
        , records: hasMany('record')
        , site: belongsTo("site")
    });

    App.Record = DS.Model.extend({
            name: attr('string'),
            type: attr('string'),
            data: attr('string'),
            belongsTo: attr('place')
    });
```

As indicated into ember-data 1.0.0 Transition Guide, it uses promises to retrieve data, but here, nothing happens.

Here is a JSbin to see what I mean:
http://jsbin.com/iMEdOCe/6/

When I navigate to a place, I should have at least one record displayed.

I cannot figure out how to load and display the records. What do I miss ?

Is there a better way to display an array of sub-items of a model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of two issues in ember-data 1.0.0-beta.1

The lack of display is due to hasMany/belongsTo relationships: commenting these lines into App.Place and App.Record make something displayed.

However another problem appears: the 'data' keyword should not be used.

Replacing it with something like 'datapath' makes it work.`

EDIT:
Problem solved with Ember-data 1.0.0-beta.2

Comment: I think that commenting the belongs to works because you have this mapping: `belongsTo: attr('place')`, and what you want is: `place: belongsTo('place')`.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I am confused because your advice works with my jsbin, but not on my local machine. I continue debugging

Comment: OK, I finally found and it was tricky: after copy pasting from jsbin to my local server, I still had the same behaviour (nothing displayed below room description). But then, I remove the part after # from the URL, hit return. And then hard reseted my page and... miracle it worked... until I navigate several times and it then disappeared. Obviously it is a bug from ember. It happens each time I reset the URL.